# Cannot test WebClient exception situation

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, webclient

I use Spring WebClient and write a test by following [this](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/02/07/webclient-integration-test/) page.

Everything is ok except from the exception test. I tried to use many different exception classes, but each time I get:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting a throwable with cause being an instance >of:java.lang.RuntimeException but current throwable has no cause.

The test method is here:

```
@Test
void throwsProductServiceExceptionWhenErrorStatus() throws JsonProcessingException {
    server.enqueue(
            new MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(500)
                    .setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .setBody("{}"));

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> client.findByName("flower"))
            .hasCauseInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class);
    // I also tried many other exception types e.g. JsonProcessingException
}
```

Here is my WebClient method that I want to create exception test:

```
private String fetchData(String title, String uri) {
    // make GET call with WebClient.get and use a Mono of String to get the response as JSON string
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uri, title)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                    error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(ERROR_WHEN_FETCHING_DATA)))
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
}
```

Any idea?